# React SetState with destructured variable is providing erroneous results

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using my `handleChange()` for multiple inputs based on their name attribute.

On input change i'm setting state as follows:

`this.setState({['user.' + event.target.name]: event.target.value});`

I am using user as a string in the destructure to setstate into user objects.
so instead of getting:

`user:{userName:'asdasd',userEmail:'ada@asdas.com'}`

I actually get:

[image]

Essentially, my question is: How can I keep using `handleChange()` to treat different callers with the destructured object key, yet still be nested under user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it

```
const user = {...this.state.user}
user[event.target.name] = event.target.value
this.setState({
    user
})
```